# react redux not rerendering unless refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I've spend hours can't understand why there's no state change in redux if I login and did not refresh my app.

My action

```
export function applyAd(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, { emit }) => {
    dispatch({ type: APPLYING_AD })

    axios
      .put(`/ad/apply`, { id })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200 && res.data.status === 1) {
          dispatch({
            type: APPLY_AD,
            payload: res.data.data
          })

        }
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log('res',res)
      })
  }
}
```

My reducer

```
//...
case APPLYING_AD:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading_apply_ad: true
}
case APPLY_AD:
  return {
    ...state,
    ad: {
      ...state.ad,
      status: action.payload.ad.status,
      loading_apply_ad: false
   }
}
//...
```

I'm so sick, this bug caused me stuck for more than 2 days I can't even know why it doesn't rerender (it will work after I refresh after signin). I compared the state after login and logged in and refresh, the states are the same.

Comment: Where is `applyAd` called from?

Comment: plz provide component code.